# Change the name of a button in Checkout Form In magento1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, payment

I want to change the **name** of my **continue** button in **Checkout** form but I couldn't able to find the **path**. The image below will show you the button.

[image]

**Help Me to find it**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/checkout/onepage

payment.phtml

```
<div class="buttons-set" id="payment-buttons-container">
    <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
    <p class="back-link"><a href="#" onclick="checkout.back(); return false;"><small>&laquo; </small><?php echo $this->__('Back') ?></a></p>
    <button type="button" class="button" onclick="payment.save()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue') ?></span></span></button>
    <span class="please-wait" id="payment-please-wait" style="display:none;">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>" class="v-middle" /> <?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

you have to change button on this template.

> NOTE: if you are using custom module for checkout than you have to check module
>   templates to change button text.

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: welcome bro. i have tried and i found it as working so i gave this you solution.

Comment: Yes it is working for me too. Thnx for your precious time..

Comment: if you solve issue than accept this answer so it can be helpful to our stack overflow buddies.

Comment: Yes Bro I did it...

Comment: Mention not Bro :)

Answer (score 2):

`admin panel -> system -> configuration -> developer`

set `Current Configuration Scope: main website or store`

in `debug`

`Template Path Hints` `yes`
 you can see this file payemnt methid

```
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml
```

Comment: Thnx for your concern

Answer (score 2):

Add a line to the translate csv table.

You are better off changing these by translation that by mucking with templates. Translate is easily changed, if you do it as a template modification, you will always have to remember to check the code every time you upgrade to make sure version changes are reflected in your modified template.